# datepicker and css style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem with a date picker that I attached to my page
the style of the date picker is overridden by another style, and it makes the datepicker bad
the file which affect the datepicker style is
[the css sheets](http://adelandtharwat.com/testrania/stylesheets/foundation.css)

but when I put this .css online I got this result
[the current view](http://adelandtharwat.com/testrania/daytour-el-minya-cairo.html)

any help!

Comment: [the correct one should be like this](http://adelandtharwat.com/testrania/correct.JPG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is width in smoothness.css file

```
.ui-datepicker {
    display: none;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    width: 17em;//remove this line then it will work or change into auto
}
```

Comment: one thing more please
I have .js file [here](http://adelandtharwat.com/testrania//javascripts/foundation.min_old.js) that disable the datepicker at all when I put it online
thanks on advnce

Answer (score 0):

LESS might be a perfect solution. Convert the CSS to LESS by add a scope like this

```
#myId{
  .ui-datepicker {
          ... /* width:auto; (in example) */
  }
}
```

Now convert it back via LESS2CSS to

```
#myId .ui-datepicker{
   ...
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

add `!important;`  to the end of any CSS styles that are clashing with the other style sheet but you want them to be the ones taking effect

Comment: Never use `!important` when you can avoid it.